# html5 canvas draw circle variables with extra data

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw

So I am basically trying to create a seating chart that will mark spots with circles and then onMouseover displays a tooltip with the person’s first name, last name, and maybe some other information. I will likely be using Kinetic.JS for region/tooltip support as I seem to come across tutorials for it most often.

I would like to create 1 variable per person that contains not only the naming info, but also some details about the circle, this may be simple but I am new to JS in general. This is what I have come up with more as theory since it doesn’t seem to actually work this simply:

```
Function seat(centerX, centerY, radius, fillStyle, firstName, lastName, id) {
    This.centerX=ctx.arc(centerX);
    This.centerY=ctx.arc(centerY);
    This.radius=ctx.arc(radius);
    This.fillStyle=ctx.fillStyle;
    This.firstName=firstName;
    This.lastName=lastName;
    This.id=id;
}
var johnSmith = new seat (100, 120, 10, #999, John, Smith, 123);

                var canvas = document.getElementById("seatingChart");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(johnSmith);
    ctx.moveTo(…);
    ctx.arc(nextPerson);
    ect…
```

I know in order for a circle to work properly I need to have the last part of the arc info somewhere `ctx.arc(.., .., .., 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);` I am just not sure where it should be so i don't have to repeat it for every variable?

Would someone be willing to help me set this set up in the proper way? I am currently working my way through a JS book, but simply can’t seem to get this setup properly..

Thanks

Comment: "this" must be lowercase and "#999" must be in quotations

Comment: The word processor I used to write this is responsible for the uppercases, but this is really just theory code to try and explain my idea. Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jcubed says: "You cannot pass an object to arc containing those properties."

What you could do is to create your own function like:

```
context.fillPerson = function(p){
    this.fillStyle = p.fillStyle;
    this.arc(p.centerX,p.centerY,p.radius,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    this.fill();
}
```

If you do it this way, you can also easily change how to draw a person in the future.

If you only want it to be easier to draw cricles in general you could do:

```
context.circle = function(x,y,r){ this.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI,false); }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I changed my answer decision to it because I found it to be the easier of the two to implement and at least for me the easier to understand and expand on. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call functions in javascript like that. You have to have comma separated parameters, like `ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startingAngle, endingAngle, antiClockwise);`. You **cannot** pass an object to arc containing those properties.

Do:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStlye = johnSmith.fillStyle;
ctx.arc(johnSmith.centerX, johnSmith.centerY, johnSmith.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fill();
```

for every person, like in a for loop or something.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Once I have defined all the people can I put them in an array and just loop through them?..I imagine that way if I had buttons to load different people I could have those sets simply call each of those positions from the array?

Comment: Yes, you can. The easiest way would be to use a for in loop, like: `for (index in people) { code with people[index] instead of johnSmith; }`

Comment: Note that using the [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) method you _can_ use an array of values as the explicit arguments to a function.